# How can i add additional IP address to my ubuntu server?

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I am using Ubuntu server 14.04.

I am connecting to internet via dhcp protocol.

Right now i connected one more NICs/Lan Cards and i want to assign them IPs.

So as a final result my server will be reachable from anywhere from 2 different IPs.

Here is what i have when i use `dmesg | grep -i network`:

```
[    0.795910] Initalizing network drop monitor service
[    0.919285] Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - version 7.3.21-k5-NAPI
[    1.270140] e1000: eth0: e1000_probe: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.617240] e1000: eth1: e1000_probe: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
```

I do not know how to configure it, how to enable the 1 new lan card and how to assign them with IP.

Can you please help me out resolve this ?

Comment: Note that if you want it reachable 'from anywhere' (on the internet), you will need to talk to your ISP about getting a second IP address - local won't help. There will likely be a charge for this, and they might require you to move up to a business plan. IPv6 might be an option, if your client devices are all on IPv6 networks?

Comment: I am on a DHCP network where i can assign a static IP just providing my ISP with the MAC address. This is how i receive IPs. My questions is how to assign 2IPs with two different MAC addresses both connected on one machine.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that your NICs are identified by ubuntu, so you can see their configs with `ifconfig` command.

And then you can edit file `/etc/network/interfaces` to change their configs.

For exmaple you can edit this way:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.56.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.56.1
```

to config eth0 with static ip address.

But if you want to have dhcp, you write as follow:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

And don't forget to restart networking with the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

For more info please refer to [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic).

Comment: I have this `iface eth0 inet dhcp` but this is for my old nic. I have to configure eth1 and and eth2 for static configuration ?

Comment: What's your `ifcongfig` output?

Comment: You can use `dmesg | grep -i network` to find out that all of your NICs have been identified.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you amend your `/etc/network/interfaces` file to read something like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.1.160
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

Be sure to select addresses outside the DHCP range set in the router. Substitute your details here. Restart the interfaces:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
sudo ifdown eth1 && sudo ifup -v eth1
```

Check:

```
ifconfig
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Restarting networking is now deprecated.

Comment: Is it necessary to add dns-nameservers and how can i see my netmask and gateway ?

Comment: It is only necessary to specify DNS nameservers if you expect to reach the internet. They are required to resolve names, www.ubuntu.com, for example, into numbers that the internet can use and understand; in this case, 91.189.89.118. Your netmask is almost certainly as I stated above. The gateway is the address of the router, switch or other access point to which you attach. You may find it by referring to other connected devices on the same network; an iPad or Windows computer, for example.

Comment: So there is no need to set up DNS nameservers in order to just make this server accessible from anywhere with 2 IPs ?

Comment: Won't you need to access the internet for updates, etc.?

Comment: I have dhcp right now and i can access the internet with no problem without any DNSes. Why i need them there ?

Comment: DHCP supplies the address, netmask, gateway *AND* DNS nameservers. Without DHCP, it is up to the user to specify these details.

Comment: Okey but i do not know how to get the netmask of my IP, either the gateway or DNS...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37342/discussion-between-chili555-and-tony-stark).